# JavaScript heap out of memory when building Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to build a vue.js app for production. This error message always appears midway through.

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I already tried to increase the memory by adding `--max_old_space_size=4096` and even tried to change it to 8192, but to no avail. I am using a Mac with 8 GB of RAM so I'm not sure why this is happening.

This is the code I run for *npm run build*:

```
vue-cli-service build --max_old_space_size=4096
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into this problem too. The memory limitation was with Node so running this command worked:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 npm run build
```

On Windows, use:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 
npm run build
```

The default memory limit for Node is 512MB, running this command temporarily increased it to 4GB.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me. I am building an application with `vue` and `laravel`. I am using dynamic components with `keep-alive` and max number of components to be kept alive is `5`. I am using `npm run watch` to watch for changes in the `vue` app. However, during the development I randomly encounter the issue which OP described above and the `watch` shuts down as well. My question is, is this a concern when I send the application to production? Why does this suddenly happen? Is this happening because of dynamic components or `keep-alive`? Can this also happen on production? Please help me!

Comment: @S.Farooq - I think it would be good if you created this as a standalone question, there's a bunch of possibilities, which are hard to explore using the comments system.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to expanding my WSL memory to 5gb by editing .wslconfig file in $USER$ folder in windows.