# javascript heap out of memory when npm run serve in vuejs project?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, error-handling

I am creating a project in Vue JS and using below command:

```
npm run serve
```

It throws an error:

> javascript heap out of memory

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842735/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-when-building-vue-js-app

Comment: I found the solution. cd to your project directory and type `npm run lint`. This will show all the errors in vue project, try removing those errors and vuejs project will run fine without throwing heap out of memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. cd to your project directory and type `npm run lint`. This will show all the errors in vue project, try removing those errors and vuejs project will run fine without throwing heap out of memory error. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large project with each .less file in every folder(such as components, views) you may have this problem.

> I have solved it by move all .less file into just one folder
>   "/assets/less/" and import all of them to "/assets/less/index.less"

Another option is adding a script to package.json, so you can run "npm run dev" instead of "npm run serve". But this option will not resolved the root of this problem.

```
"dev": "npx --max_old_space_size=4096 vue-cli-service serve"
```